# What does this icon in Disk Utility mean?

Tags: 19.10, zfs

[image: Screenshot]

As shown in the screenshot, there are strange icons on two seagate HDD. What does it mean? This is on Ubuntu 19.10 with zfs enabled.

Comment: Does it indicate that those drives are added zfs pools - ie zpools?

Comment: @Graham nope. 256GB nvme is a zpool. Two 8T drives make up a mirrored zpool. Two 3T drives are using exFAT. Only seagates drives have this icon though.

Answer (score 3):

I raised an [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/-/issues/180) about it with the gnome-disk-utility developers, and it seems to be a theming issue in Ubuntu.

The presence of an icon probably indicates the disk is in standby, and it should likely be a sort of "ZZZ" icon, as seen in https://www.worldofgnome.org/a-preview-of-gnome-disks-3-6/ :

[image: gnome-disk-utility zzz]

Based on their advice I filed a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/2324) for the Yaru theme, and this has been fixed in their main branch, although this doesn't seem to have propagated to 20.04 yet...

Comment: I have 5 disks showing it all on one StorageWOrks array as a JBOD... but they are definitely not in standby.

Comment: The symbol shown seems to just be a standard Disk Utility icon, so maybe it’s shown as a placeholder whenever a status icon is missing. Sadly my request for tooltips in the bug report hasn’t been picked up on.. I guess a distro with a vanilla Gnome theme might give you a better icon?